# bundle install leads to git clone error. Not sure what this response means

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, clone

Getting a strange error on bundle install..

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.....
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching git://github.com/maccman/gdata.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/maccman/gdata.git' "/Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@shasta/cache/bundler/git/gdata-811f852468ac76e0019108d8c5320da12b6683d4" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /Users/elephanttrip/Sites/shasta has failed.
```

This wasn't happening until I installed the mysql2 gem and mysql with brew.

Any ideas what this error means?

**UPDATE**

Also none of the folders it is trying to clone this to exist. It's probably something to do with my bundle paths and juggling .rvm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is not on your end. Trying:

```
git clone 'git://github.com/maccman/gdata.git' "foobar" --bare --no-hardlinks
```

Fails on my machine with the same error.

Interestingly a non-bare clone seems to work as expected.

**resolution:** Clone from the https interface: `https://github.com/maccman/gdata.git` instead.

Comment: Ah, amazing. Thanks for pointing that out my European comrade. I'll just comment that piece out. ;D

Comment: Well, I might not be so fast, you'll probably need the gdata API :)

Comment: I switched it to the https connection and it worked. Interesting to say the least.

Comment: This is probably something to take up to the github team.

Answer (score 5):

1. In your Terminal write `bundle config github.https true`
2. In your Terminal write `bundle install`

Answer (score -2):

Add your SSH key to the github.

Or as @brice mentioned, you need to add your team to the repo.